# INSERT BYTE[] TO Sql Without parameter

Tags: c#, sql

I want to make a raw SQL query that adds an encrypted value (`byte[]`) to an SQL column (`varbinary`) without using parameter like this:

```
 byte[] value = GetEncryptedValue();
 string query = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('" + value.ToString() + "')";
```

the column datatype that I want insert into is `varbinary`.  I need some function that uses value.ToString() instead. How to write this ?
i just need function like master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr in sql!!!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't use want to use a parameter?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @usr it can be useful. For example, you need to generate `INSERT ...` from existing data and apply to some other DB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A binary literal takes the form `0x6ABCDEF`, i.e. `0x` followed by bytes in hexadecimal form.

You can use this to turn the byte array into a literal value:

```
string literal = "0x" + String.Join("", value.Select(n => n.ToString("X2")));
```

There are not apostrophes around the binary literal:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(" + literal + ")";
```

Comment: @usr: The OP specifically asked for a solution without using a parameteried query.

Comment: Did not see that. What an odd requirement and he's probably mistaken with that. I fixed a typo in your code.

Comment: @user1704457: Try with the code as it looks now, with `0h` in the code, not `0x`. That was an edit made by usr.

Comment: "SELECT 0h12345f" does not work. Is it supposed to? "SELECT 0x12345f" does.

Comment: I JUST NEED FUNCTION LIKE master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr IN SQL

Comment: @Guffa never saw that form either, the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179366(v=sql.90).aspx) is also using "0x4F" so where did you see such form used?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: From the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swbw1ewb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: That's for foxpro it seems. Or Access. Just not SQL Server.

Comment: @Guffa I don't think the OP here is using Visual FoxPro, more likely SQL Server.

Comment: This question will teach me not trying to work on such vague and misguided questions. It is unclear to me if the OP even wants this solution. He just said he wants a T-SQL solution if I interpret his rude and vague statement correctly. We are all wasting our time here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It seems that you are right. It's hard to find the right documentation for this, but my actual tests shows that it should be `0x`, not `0h`.

Comment: True, wonder though if we don't need `SELECT fn_varbintohexstr([hex literal here])` to make it actually work?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, that's not needed, a binary literal can be used directly to insert into a varbinary field.

Comment: @user1704457: Where's the difference, and is that a difference in one byte, or one character in the literal, i.e. half a byte?

Comment: @Guffa : the difference is my fault in encryption.my problem solved . i want to say thanks a lot to you

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, is by using `BitConverter`

```
byte[] value = GetEncryptedValue();
string query = 
    "INSERT INTO Table1 (c1) VALUES(0x" + BitConverter.ToString(value).Replace("-", "") + ")";
```

`BitConverter.ToString` returns something like `01-02-03....`